# 'console.log' does not work in Webstorm in testing Electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, electron

In a "normal" node application in Webstorm (Windows 7) I can use `console.log` to write to the console window of Webstorm.

As soon as I use Electron to create a desktop app the console outputs are no longer shown in the Webstorm console window although I use the same node command 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe'. The main difference is that in the run configuration I have to use a node parameter 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\cli.js' to get the right Electron entry point.

When I directly start the Electron application from a Windows console window then this console window shows all the outputs.

The problem might be related to the fact that 'cli.js' spawns a child process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var electron = require('./')

var proc = require('child_process')

var child = proc.spawn(electron, process.argv.slice(2), {stdio: 'inherit'});
child.on('close', function (code) {
  process.exit(code);
})
```

But this one inherits `stdio` and therefore the outputs should go to the same channel. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: You need TO open The console on Electron

Comment: Just like a normal chrome browser would do

Comment: I tried this. The output is not in this console. I'm new at Electron but as I understand it there is a main process (where I use the 'console.log') and there are renderer processes which handle the "web" pages in Electron. For the later ones I would expect the output to occur in the Chromium console. For the main process I would not expect this and it obviously does not happen. But why don't I see the output in the starting console window?

Comment: What do you see if you execute the command `electron .` using the terminal, in your project folder?

Comment: If I call it outside Webstorm then I see the outputs in the Windows 7 terminal window (as I said above). But if I start it with Webstorm the outputs are somehow lost.

Comment: Seems just an Eclipse terminal issue, I don't know about that unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems there is no easy solution to that because it probably is a Webstorm bug. It is tracked here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17029. The bug is known for six months. Sorry for not finding out earlier (and wasting your time ;-).